# Volume slider disappears when using Auto Layout

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

I have an app which plays streamed radio stations.

I've recently updated it for iPhone 5 and iPad

For the most part auto layout takes care of the hard work aside from my custom table which I resize depending on the screen height detected.

Weirdly however my volume slider which is just the standard stock object disappears completely when running on the iPhone 5. It's not moving or hiding in a completely unseen location it's just gone.

I've even tried building a view with the slider and nothing else and moving it to the centre of the view but the problem persists. Is this a bug or am I missing the obvious? It's driving me crazy and I'm getting a lot of customer complaints.

Comment: Can't tell anything without knowing what your constraints are. Sometimes, the only way constraints can be satisfied, if they're set up incorrectly, is for the object to have zero size, which could be your problem.

Comment: Agree with rdelmar, hard to provide any meaningful help without any knowledge of what your constraints are. If describing them is too tedious, you can always open your .xib file with a text editor and paste the relevant portions here (since a screenshot won't contain enough info to help)